# Spring-python JMS receiver. MQSCO wrong size. Given: 540, expected 560

Tags: python, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to JMS queue by spring-python. I take example of receiver from official spring python site

```
enter code herefrom springpython.jms.core import JmsTemplate
from springpython.jms.factory import WebSphereMQConnectionFactory

qm_name = "my_qmname"
channel = "my_channel"
host = 'my_host'
listener_port = 'my_port'
queue1 = "MY_QUEUE"

# The connection factory we're going to use.
factory = WebSphereMQConnectionFactory(qm_name, channel, host, listener_port)

# Every JmsTemplate uses a connection factory for actually communicating with a JMS provider.
jms_template = JmsTemplate(factory)

# Get a message off the queue. The call to receive will by default time out
# after 1000ms and raise springpython.jms.NoMessageAvailableException then.
jms_template.receive(queue1)

# We're not using an IoC so we need to shut down the connection factory ourselves.
factory.destroy()
```

And i get next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Repos/provisioning/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    jms_template.receive('MY_QUEUE')
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\springpython\jms\core.py", line 108, in receive
    return self.factory.receive(dest, timeout)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\springpython\jms\factory.py", line 327, in receive
    self._connect()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\springpython\util.py", line 45, in lockedfunc
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\springpython\jms\factory.py", line 211, in _connect
    raise exc
springpython.jms.WebSphereMQJMSException: MQSCO wrong size. Given: 540, expected 560
```

As i found MQSCO is something related to SSL, how can i fix the problem?
Thank you